# How to run a server JAR file with RMI, directly from within Java code in that same JAR file

Tags: rmi, java

I am trying to deploy a jar file on a tomcat server and initialise RMI. For this I am using the following command--

```
 java -jar -Djava.security.policy=[rmi.policy file path] server.jar [server_ip] [port]
```

Now, I want the above initialisation and RMI Policy file, and port (for RMI) to be directly done by Java code within the same Jar file.

How do I do this? Also, can I use a URL instead of the IP address?

Comment: What happens if you enter a URL in the browser: the browser performs a 'DNS-lookup' to turn the URL into an IP-address (AFAIK). So, you can use a URL too, but then you'll have to do a DNS-lookup too.

Comment: @11684 The relevance of your comment escapes me. There are no URLs in this question.

Comment: @EJP-- 11684 is talking of URLs because the RMI service will be accessed by a IP address- which can instead be replaced with a domain name (at which point the DNS lookup will happen)...

Comment: @EJP you might want to re-read the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0):

java.security.policy is a system property, and can be set with System.setProperty(). You don't need to set command line arguments from within the code, as you are just talking to yourself: just use those values in the appropriate places.